# Positioning and aligning HTML text

Tags: html, text, alignment, indentation

How can I write HTML code to produce output like this:

Calculation 1:       2

Calculation 2:       2

Calculation 3:       2

Total:               8

However I need all the numbers to be aligned ^ about here in the page

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? And how is this related to Java (unless you are putting this into a JLabel).

Comment: You're right, java does not apply I will remove that tag. I am using java in the code that this comes from that's why I accidentally added it.

Comment: And no, I have been researching it but don't even know where to start

Comment: I suggest right-clicking the `Calculation 1: 2` part, pressing **Inspect Element** from the list, and checking out the code SO used to post your question. EDIT: Check out your question's code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gwt9qdw1/)

Comment: Right, but that doesn't hold any clues as to how it would be aligned with the others

Comment: `<p align="center">foo</p>` EDIT: Oh, I see; just the numbers. You can use &nbsp; for spaces, but I guess that is gruesome work, copy-pasting `&nbsp;` ten times.

Answer (score 1):

Tables will do the trick!

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/rupbwpx0/1/

```
  <table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td>Calculation 1:</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Calculation 2:</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Calculation 3:</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is for markup and if you want to layout, then use CSS. The following HTML code will show exactly what you are looking for and it could be also styled with CSS.

```html
<div class="main">
  <span>Calculation 1:</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>  
<div class="main">
  <span>Calculation 2:</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span>Calculation 3:</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span>Total:</span>
  <span>8</span>
</div>
```